# Google maps api not working. Was working before I added the api key

Tags: api, maps

I have a website with google maps, it always used to work, but started getting a message saying "This page can't load Google Maps correctly", the chrome extension said it was that there was no API key, but when I added a key, it just stopped loading the map, with the reason that the copyright was not visible, and no, I didn't remove it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What code did you use to link the API?

Comment: <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: And the client id